# Woocommerce - Clear cart on user logout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in wordpress site.

I need to clear cart contents of a logged in user when that user logs out.

I am unable to find any options for the same in plugin settings.

Anyone let me know a way to achieve the same.

Comment: I don't think this is too broad. Clearing cart on user logout is pretty specific and easily solved using Karthik's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `wp_logout` hook to empty the cart. Place the below code in your theme's `function.php` or in your own plugin.

```
function your_function() {
    if( function_exists('WC') ){
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function');
```

Edited: According to @helgatheviking 's solution

Comment: Is this correct and working way , because I can be able to see that some functions were deprecated in Woocommerce

Comment: You should 1. switch `$woocommerce` to `WC()` (because the global variable is deprecated in favor of using the function to return the instance of the plugin) and 2. check that the `WC` function exists. That way if WooCommerce is ever deactivated you won't end up with a fatal error.

Comment: As per the comment from Plugin author is saying that it is working by default , No need to add code.
My server is Nginx , Whether it is a reason.?

Comment: What are you asking now? This perfectly answers the question of how to clear the cart on logout and should be the accepted answer.