# Woocommerce cart is not clear after logout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am implementing an LMS using one plus theme,learndash and woocommerce plugins.
Currently when a user log out, his cart persist and the item in his cart can be edited by a guest user.I want to clear the cart after a user logout from his account.I tried the answer, given in  this link for fixing the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785631/6270441.
I tried putting this code in my themes function.php,but it is not working.

```
function your_function() {
    if( function_exists('WC') ){
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check how your hosting company is caching pages, and make sure that your cart is being excluded from the cache / CDN at the host.  Nine times out of ten this is the source of the problem you are describing.

Comment: I have hosted the site  with Bigrock.How to check it?

Comment: THIS is the answer for my eCommerce problems! I asked the hosting company to exempt the cart and checkout pages from caching, and my problem was immediately solved!